# Spring's @Autowire annotation returns null on JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am building a web application using spring-data-jpa, but now I have error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.example.test.demo.config.service.RegionServiceImpl.getAll(RegionServiceImpl.java:40)
    at com.example.test.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:45)
```

Repository:

```
import com.example.test.demo.config.entity.Region;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RegionRepository extends JpaRepository<Region, Integer> {

}
```

Service:

```
@Component
public class RegionServiceImpl implements RegionService {

  @Autowired
  private RegionRepository regionRepository;
```

And model:

```
@Entity
//@Table(name = "geo.region")
@Table(name = "region", schema = "geo")
public class Region implements Serializable {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  public Region() {
  }
```

But now I have NPE on this step:

```
@Autowired
private RegionRepository regionRepository;
```

Pls, help! :(

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: How do you create a `RegionServiceImpl`?

Comment: Include your configuration too.

Comment: Create from     `RegionServiceImpl s = new RegionServiceImpl();`

Comment: @ОлегМихайлов you need to let spring initialize your service, else the repository will not get injected

Comment: Ohhh, I forgon this! Yes, it is working now thanks